# How to turn on screen programatically (2014)

Tags: android

I have developed an App that loads automatically when smartphone receives an SMS message.

Problem is that if screen's phone is off or in "black" mode, App doesn't load when SMS arrives. I need that my app turn screen on programmatically. Is that possible? I found several past answers but no one has worked.

I tried:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params =
                getWindow().getAttributes();
                params.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                params.screenBrightness = 0;
                getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

And tried:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.my_main_activity);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

**EDIT:**

I tried suggestion:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

But strangely Android Studio gives me errors:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED'
```

[image]

Comment: What's that '2014' ?!

Comment: Because several answers that I found were from 2011 and 2012. I don't know if some of these are obsolete because newer android versions.

Comment: What's your target API? `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` has been around since API 5, so it's highly unlikely that Studio should complain about that. Further, the `Turn_Screen_On` method name (besides it not being lower-case, per convention), makes me wonder how you attempt to use this. You shouldn't be calling this... the window flags should be set in `onCreate()`, so any time you bring up the Activity, it turns on the screen, if off.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, but rather `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD`, `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` and `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`:

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Make sure you're using [`WindowManager.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED).

Comment: Android Studio shows me error: Cannot resolve symbol 'FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED'.... Any import that I should set?

Comment: Make sure you're using `WindowManager.LayoutParams`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides excellent answer of @323go, I learnt that:

- Appropriate SDK or API version should be setup in build.gradle

  android {

  ```
  signingConfigs {
      config {
      }
  }
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId 'com.calisalasapp'
      minSdkVersion 8
  }
  ```
- All appropriate API versions should be installed in SDK Manager